# Inserting colon after editors with bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I am using bibtex and I have created my own style file. Unfortunately there is one option I could not find yet: I want to insert a colon after the editors' names in an incollection.

Now it looks like:
[...] In: Doe, J. (ed.) My greatest book of all time [..]

But instead it shall look like:
[...] In: Doe, J. (ed.): My greatest book of all time [..]

Does anyone know how to edit the .dbj file or another package/option to get this to work?

Many thanks for your support in advance!